# Access .env variables in js file Laravel. Not in blade file

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I've set the following keys in my `.env` file.

```
AGOLIA_APP_KEY="appKey"
AGOLIA_APP_SECRET="appSecret"
AGOLIA_APP_INDEX="appIndex"
```

I want to access these variables in my script file `agolia.js` as the following.

```
    let client = algoliasearch(
        process.env.AGOLIA_APP_KEY,
        process.env.AGOLIA_APP_SECRET
    );
    let index = client.initIndex(process.env.AGOLIA_APP_INDEX);
```

With the above config. Laravel mix compiles the file with success but instead of variables same string text are seen in compiled file.

**I.E: process.env.AGOLIA_APP_KEY**

How can I access `.env` variables in javascript files ? Most of the answers were about accessing in

Comment: You can't, and I think it is not a good idea. Your app_secret will not be secret anymore if you place it in a js file.. Think of it this way, if the .env would be available in js, I would be able to read your database credentials from the browser console too

Comment: Did you use `php artisan config:clear`?
Also this link might useful for you. https://discourse.algolia.com/t/process-env-mix-algolia-app-id-not-recognized-in-laravel-vue-app/8939

Comment: @GertB. Yes i know. But it is good to change in one place than many files.

Comment: @RBC yes I did same result

Comment: @psudo In one place is better, just not in a public js file :-D, on a server side node js file you can read the .env